# iOS : How to extract value for a key in JSON object

Tags: ios, json, web-services, xcode4.5

1. I have one QR-Code image. I scan that image in iOS and get one url.
2. I posted that URL to the webservice through JSON object and get one "ProjectID" in return.
3. If that projectID has a positive value, I should return YES indicating that the scanned URL is valid for the webservice else return NO.

[For testing purpose I have hardcoded the URL which should return YES. I will get the scanned URL later]

How to extract the projectID I get in log and check the condition.

Here's what I coded

```
NSError *error;

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"test@yahoo.com" ,@"EmailID", @"http://www.yahoo.com", @"URL", @"", @"Phone", @"", @"UserID", nil];


   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:// some url"];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody: requestData];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:180];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
       [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
       if(error || !data)
       {
           NSLog(@"JSON NOT posted");
       }
        else
        {
            id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:Nil];

            if([jsonObject respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)])
            {
                NSDictionary *dictionaryForUserID = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"ProjID"];
                NSLog(@" Project Id = %@", dictionaryForUserID); 

    /* I get "Project ID = (null)"  here whereas I get one positive value in the log. My question is how to get the projectID in log? */

    /* log output ::

    2013-08-20 11:57:34.765 appname[585:5903]  Project Id = (null)

    2013-08-20 11:57:34.766 appname[585:5903] JSON data posted!

    2013-08-20 11:57:34.769 appname[585:c07] Data: 
    {"ProjID":"5","ProjName":null,"URL":null,"EmailID":null,"Phone":null,"userId":null}{"ProjID":"5","ProjName":null,"URL":null,"EmailID":null,"Phone":null,"userId":null}

    */

            }
            NSLog(@"JSON data posted!");
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Please format your codes what error is returned when you call `JSONObjectWithData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you are parsing your request data instead of the response data.

Try this instead:

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:Nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at your code. You are parsing `requestData`, not the `data` that's received from the server. Good Luck!